# Approximations of the kind $x \ll y$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, approximations

I have an expression for a force due to charged particle given as
$$F=\frac{kQq}{2L}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2+(H+L)^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2+(H-L)^2}}\right) \tag{1}$$ where $R$, $L$ and $H$ are distance quantities.

Now I want to check what happens when:

1. $H\gg R,L$
2. $R,H\ll L$

How can I work out the approximation of this force?
Do I have to write it slightly different into form (2) to get it right?
$$ ~F=\frac{kqQ}{2LR}\left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{H+L}{R}\right)^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{H-L}{R}\right)^2}}\right) \tag{2}$$ (which is the same expression just written out differently). Any  explain about this subject would be very helpful.

Comment: I am afraid that your question is more suitable for the mathematics SE.

Comment: @Sofia I disagree. Why do you think that? It's about using a type of approximation common in electrostatics...

Comment: This kind of homework-like question is off-topic for our site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's focus just on the interesting bit of the equation:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2+(H+L)^2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2+(H-L)^2}} =\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2+H^2+2HL+L^2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2+H^2-2HL+L^2}}$$

Now if $H>>L,R$, we are left just with the terms with $H$:

$$\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{H^2+2HL}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{H^2-2HL}}\\
=\frac{1}{H}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2\frac{L}{H}}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2\frac{L}{H}}}\right)\\
\approx \frac{1}{H}\left(1-\frac12 \cdot 2\frac{L}{H}-\left(1+\frac12\cdot 2 \frac{L}{H}\right)\right)\\
=-\frac{2L}{H^2}$$

Almost exactly the same approach works for $L>>R, H$ (I will leave the details up to you).

Comment: I like how you removed the $R^2$ terms, which was an obvious move. But why bother approximating away the $L^2$? Once $R^2$ is gone, you have $\sqrt{(H\pm L)^2}$. The square root cancels the square, which leaves a nice $(H\pm L)$. Obviously, if you carry through simplifying that, you can still work it into the same result you got here, but it definitely makes for easier intermediate steps

Comment: @JimsBond - yes, I see your point. And re-reading your answer, I believe that is what you did...

Answer (score 5):

For $H\gg R,L$ And for $L\gg R,H$ you get pretty much the same thing.

First off, $(H+L)^2\sim H^2$ and the same goes for $(H-L)^2$. That means that $(H+L)^2+R^2\approx (H+L)^2$. However, $(H+L)\not\approx H$, which means that $\sqrt{R^2+(H+L)^2}\approx H+L$. This makes the first approximation have $\frac{1}{H+L}-\frac{1}{H-L}$ in it.

The second approximation proceeds much the same way. $R$ is approximated away and you are left with the root of $(H\pm L)^2$. The resulting approximations should be identical

Answer (score 2):

Your final expression is off by a minus sign, and is not what you want.  For #1, $H$ is large, so I'd factor $H$ out.  For #2, $L$ is large, so I'd factor $L$ out.

When you factor out a large thing, the remaining things are either numbers (which are what they are) or small things.  And when something is small you can approximate it by comparing it to other things.

Comment: Do I have to manage the expression a different way to work out the limit?

Answer (score 2):

When considering these things, at least as a warm up to a more rigorous answer, it is worth thinking about what it means to say that $H>>R$. I take this to mean that, roughly, if I add $H$ to $R$ I'm going to get something close to $H$, as it is much larger. For example $1000000>>1$ so $1000000+1\simeq1000000$. When the variables are squared, as you have, this difference is even more marked.

So, if $H>>R,L$, $(H+L)^2+R^2 \simeq (H+L)^2$, so the first term in your brackets becomes ${1 \over H+L}$ (or ${1 \over |H+L|}$). Similarly the second term, and then add the two to get something non-zero.

You can use a similar process for the second question.

A more rigorous way to do it would be to do something similar to what you and other answerers have done, which is to take out a factor from the front of your square roots which corresponds to the large variable in each case, so that you're left with dimensionless terms inside like $1, L/H$, and $R/H$. These last two can be neglected compared to 1 and you should get the same results.

Comment: For $H\gg R,L$, $(H+L)^2+R^2\approx(H+L)^2$ so the root becomes $H+L$.

Comment: You can't approximate $(H+L)^2\approx H^2$. That's not how it works. $(H+L)^2\approx H^2+2HL$

Comment: that'll teach me for responding on an empty stomach! will edit after dinner :)